# Akka streams - shutdown stream with grouping without losing data

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a source that groups elements and a sink that makes a batch request,
I'm using KillSwitch to be able to shutdown the graph at some arbitrary point in time. The problem that records of the latest incomplete batch that source outputs are getting lost when `switch.shutdown()` is being called

```
val source = Source.tick(10.millis, 10.millis, "tick").grouped(500)

val (switch, _) = source.viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()

Thread.sleep(3000) // wait some arbitrary time

switch.shutdown()
```

Is there a way to 'flush out' the incomplete batch when shutdown happens?

Answer (score 5):

The behaviour of the kill switch shutdown is positional, as per its docs

> After calling [[UniqueKillSwitch#shutdown()]] the running instance of
>   the [[Graph]] of [[FlowShape]] that materialized to the
>   [[UniqueKillSwitch]] will complete its downstream and cancel its
>   upstream (unless if finished or failed already in which case the
>   command is ignored).

See also more docs [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html#uniquekillswitch).

Now the `grouped` stage will emit a partially filled group only at completion time, but not when cancelled.

This means that the graph below (grouped **before** killswitch) will behave like you observed

```
  val switch = 
    Source.tick(10.millis, 175.millis, "tick")
          .grouped(10)
          .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
          .toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.left)
          .run()
```

whilst the graph below (grouped **after** killswitch)  will emit partial groups downstream at completion

```
  val switch =
    Source.tick(10.millis, 175.millis, "tick")
          .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
          .grouped(10)
          .toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.left)
          .run()
```

Comment: @stanislav.chetvertkov you're very welcome :) could you kindly accept the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Good answer.